# Changing an attribute value, but only if child element fulfills condition

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <cit>
      <level type="higher">
         <part>higher1</part>
         <part>higher2</part>
      </level>
      <level type="medium">
         <content>higher1 higher2</content>
      </level>
   </cit>
   <cit>
      <level type="higher">
         <part>higherA</part>
      </level>
      <level type="medium">
         <content>higherA</content>
      </level>
   </cit>
</entry>
```

I now want to change the attribute value of the `level` element from "medium" to "lower", but only if the content of the `content` child consists of two or more words.

My XSL file (XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cit/level/@type[.='medium']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">lower</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

changes the attribute value for ALL `<level>` elements, regardless of how many words they contain. I tried to insert a `<xsl:if test ...>` right after the template match definition in order to identify any whitespace in the content of the `<level type="medium">`, but to no avail. So what would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tokenize` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="cit/level[tokenize(content, '\s+')[2]]/@type[.='medium']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">lower</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7md.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! But may I still ask what the ``[2]`` in the tokenize expression exactly stands for?

Comment: It is a positional predicate that selects the second item in the sequence returned by `tokenize`, if there is a second item, and together with the use inside the outer predicate (`level[tokenize(content, '\s+')[2]]`) it is short form of checking that tokenize returned at least two items.

Comment: Which is probably not an exact match to the requirement "contains two or more words", especially if there is leading or trailing whitespace. I'd be inclined to suggest the predicate `[contains(normalize-space(), ' ')]`